# filter data on multiple fields

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am trying to build a filter for JSON object at the moment, the json object looks like this,

```
created_at: null
deleted_at: null
id: 3
listings: Array(3)
0: {id: 3, name: "Learn the basics of the guitar  from the anatomy of the  guitar to scales, chords", slug: "learn-the-basics-of-the-guitar-from-the-anatomy-of-the-guitar-to-scales-chords", description: "We live in a unique and wonderful time where elect… going to give you a lifetime of awesome rockin’.", booking_details: "undefined", …}
1: {id: 8, name: "Advanced guitar skills with William Topa", slug: "advanced-guitar-skills-with-william-topa", description: "We live in a unique and wonderful time where elect… going to give you a lifetime of awesome rockin’.", booking_details: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing… laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.", …}
2: {id: 9, name: "Music production simplified", slug: "music-production-simplified", description: "We live in a unique and wonderful time where elect… going to give you a lifetime of awesome rockin’.", booking_details: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing… laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.", …}
length: 3
__proto__: Array(0)
tag: "Music"
updated_at: null
weight: null
```

This is part of a bigger object, the hierarchy looks like

```js
[{ data, listings }, {data, listings}]
```

What I am wanting to do, is filter through the listings array and hide any listings that don't have a cost of "0.00"

Here is what i am trying,

```html
<input type="checkbox" v-model="priceFilter" value="0.00" />
```

```js
data() {
  return {
    this.priceFilter: []
  }
},
computed: {
  filteredTags() {
    return this.tags.filter(tag => {
      tag.listings.filter(listing => "0.00" === listing.cost);
      //console.log(this.checkedPrice, listing.cost);
    });
  },
},
```

In the above I just trying to return the listings where the cost matches 0.00 with trigger it via the checkbox being checked but even that does not filter as I wish I still see all listings.

Anyone care to offer any advice?

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan apologies it looks fine format wise before I posted I left my desk straight after posting it so didnt' check it. Sorry!

Comment: Check these answers: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22343437/javascript-find-child-object-in-nested-arrays