# javascript find() in nested array

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I'm trying to build a website with REACT. In the homepage you have 2 buttons, europe and usa.
Let's say you click europe. Then you see a list of all the countries in europe.
And when you click a country, you should see a list of CITIES in that country.

The question is, how can I access the items inside "cities"?.

```js
       const DATA = [
       {
        id: 1,
        title: "EUROPE",
        countries: [
            {
                id: 1,
                country: "france",
                cities: [
                    {
                        id: 1,
                        city: "paris"
                        
                    },
                    {
                        id: 2,
                        city: "toulouse"
                     
                    }
        ];

         // so at homepage, you click "europe", and on the second page i got this:

         const StateCard = () => {
         const { title } = useParams();
         const selectedData = DATA.find( d => d.title === title);
         
         return(
         <div className="main">

         {selectedData &&
          selectedData.countries.map((item, id) => {

          return (
          <div className="card-container" >
           <Link key={id} to={`${title}/${item.country}`}> {item.country} </Link>
           </div>
       );
     })}
  </div>
```

useParams gives us back the title that added to the URL after the first click,
which is "europe".
selectedData gives us back the items inside "europe":
{id: 1, title: "EUROPE", countries: Array(1)}

and now the screen shows "france". you clicked france, and now i wanna show the 2 cities inside.
all i got is:

```
const { country } = useParams();
```

which gives us "france".
but i dont know how to access the cities inside.
i tried to play with DATA.countries.find(), but whatever i put after DATA. gives me
"TypeError: Cannot read property 'find' of undefined".

sorry its so long thanks guys!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22343437/javascript-find-child-object-in-nested-arrays

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each type (continents, countries, cities) is an array. `find` won't work on `DATA.countries` because `countries` is a property of whatever continent object you select.

It may help you to divide up your data collections using a series of methods. `getContinents` gets the data as an argument, and the value of `title`. `getCountries` receives the array returned by `getContinents` - as well as the value of `country` - and returns its own array of countries, and then `getCities` `map`s over that data to return the city names.

This way you maintain a series of data collections, and the code is easier to maintain.

```js
const data = [{"id":1,"title":"EUROPE","countries":[{"id":1,"country":"france","cities":[{"id":1,"city":"paris"},{"id":2,"city":"toulouse"}]}]}];

const title = 'EUROPE';
const country = 'france';
 
const getContinents = (data, val) => data.find(obj => obj.title === title)
const getCountries = (data, val) => data.countries.find(obj => obj.country === val)
const getCities = (data) => data.cities.map(obj => obj.city);

// Pass in the data and the value of title
const continents = getContinents(data, title);

// Use the array returned from `getContinents` and the country value
const countries = getCountries(continents, country);

// Use the array returned from `getCountries`
const cities = getCities(countries);

console.log(cities);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can first find the `Country` and then on `countriesResult` you can find `citiesResult` and then can find cities from `citiesResult.cities`.

You're getting the error `**TypeError: Cannot read property 'find' of undefined**` because

what you're doing is `DATA.countries.find()`. `Data` is an array so you can't use `.countries` on it. You have to find the country using `find` or use index.

```js
const DATA = [{
  id: 1,
  title: "EUROPE",
  countries: [{
    id: 1,
    country: "france",
    cities: [{
        id: 1,
        city: "paris",
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        city: "toulouse",
      },
    ],
  }, ],
}, ];
const title = "EUROPE";
const country = "france";

const countriesResult = DATA.find((d) => d.title === title);
const citiesResult = countriesResult.countries.find(
  (c) => c.country === country
);

const result = citiesResult.cities.map((c) => c.city);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

`DATA` is an array of objects. Each item in `DATA` have `countries` array. So, you have to use `find()` on specific item in `DATA` array, and not on `DATA` array iteself. For example, you can do this:

```
DATA[0].countries.find()
```